# Mounted NTFS filesystem takes up /home space. 

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I have a 500 Gig hard drive, ubuntu on it and I need to use as much space at my home dir as possible, however, my home dir somehow has only 15 Gigs of usable space.

When I run GParted, I see three partitions 1 meg of "unallocated" space, 128 megs of unknown filesystem space and then the remaining 465 Gigs of ntfs filesystem mounted on /host. I assume that in this configuration the /home directory could possibly contain all of the 465 Gigs, but it has only 15 Gigs.

I made a wubi install, I installed ubuntu on my first 500 Gig harddrive from my second windows7 hdd (also 500 gigs). Now I have two OSes, each is on its own HDD. My intent was not to replace win7.

PS: Apologies, by 500 gigs I meant 465.76 Gigs, 500 Gigs is said in specs ;). Is it still true that I need to reinstall Ubuntu not using wubi?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu next to an existing Windows sytem? What are the 35 remaining Gb of your hdd formatted to (ext4?)

Answer (score 0):

You did a wubi install where ubuntu is entirely contained within a file in your Windows install.  It sounds like you only allocated about 15G to that file.

If your intention was to replace Windows with Ubuntu and give it the whole drive, then you will need to reinstall Ubuntu properly by booting from the disc, not running it within Windows.

Comment: Yes I made a wubi install, I installed ubuntu on my first 500 Gig harddrive from my second windows7 hdd (also 500 gigs). Now I have two OSes, each is on its own HDD. My intent was not to replace win7. PS: Apologies, by 500 gigs I meant 465.76 Gigs, 500 Gigs is said in specs ;). Is it still true that I need to reinstall Ubuntu not using wubi?

Comment: @Dave, it is possible to expand the file that the wubi install is contained in and continue to run Ubuntu nested inside windows, but if your intent is to replace Windows, then yes, you need to reinstall not using wubi.